# Arquillian remote test on Wildfly

Tags: wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

I'm new to Arquillian and I have some problems with the remote testing.
I'm trying to remote test on Wildfly using Arquillian. My Wildfly instance can be reached on port 8180 but it's runing on a local virtual machine on internal port 8080. I have set a port forwarding with Vagrant and VirtualBox

When I run my test from eclipse I got the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test playeraudio.repository.player.PlayerRepositoryTestCase public void playeraudio.repository.player.PlayerRepositoryTestCase.should_find_all_players() throws java.lang.Exception
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:136)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:245)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:422)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:259)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:321)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:422)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching request at http://0.0.0.0:8080/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=playeraudio.repository.player.PlayerRepositoryTestCase&methodName=should_find_all_players. No result returned
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.executeWithRetry(ServletMethodExecutor.java:139)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:99)
... 76 more
```

Any clue please ?

This is my arquillian.xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">


    <container qualifier="widlfly-remote" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="chameleonTarget">wildfly:8.2.1.Final:remote</property>
            <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
            <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
            <property name="managementPort">10090</property>
            <property name="username">admin</property>
            <property name="password">manager</property>
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

    <container qualifier=""></container>

    <extension qualifier="transaction">
        <property name="manager">java:jboss/UserTransaction</property>
    </extension>

    <extension qualifier="persistence">
        <property name="defaultDataSource">java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</property>
    </extension>

    <extension qualifier="persistence-script">
        <property name="scriptsToExecuteBeforeTest">SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE</property>
    </extension>

    <extension qualifier="persistence-dbunit">
        <property name="datatypeFactory">org.dbunit.ext.mssql.MsSqlDataTypeFactory</property>

    </extension>

</arquillian>
```

Comment: I have the same problem when I deploy to a Jenkins machine

Answer (score 8):

I find the solution: we need to specifiy the port for the used protocol (i.e. Servlet 3.0) in arquillian.xml file :

```
<container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="chameleonTarget">wildfly:8.2.1.Final:remote</property>
    </configuration>
    <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
        <property name="host">localhost</property>
        <property name="port">8180</property>
    </protocol>
...
```